# Firebase Firestore Kotlin Quizz QuestionList

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have question and problem. I want to create quizz with connecting firestore firebase. I create database with example question.

**How can I make the next question appear when I click on a question? What do i need to do first? There will probably be a loop somewhere. Do you list the values ​​from the firestore to and on the basis that it will be randomized?**

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val docRef = db.collection("quizz").document("question1")
docRef.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            pytanie.text = document.data?.getValue("pytanie").toString()
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "No such document")
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", exception)
    }
```

Now i have on question and set to txt.

This is my firebase

[This is my firebase firestore train database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqXs.png)

**How can i add a lot of question and change it after click on textview?**

Thanks for help and tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of logical task. So just get all quizz then iterate through them

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val docRef = db.collection("quizz")
docRef.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        var count = 0
        var questionsList:ArrayList<String>() = arrayListOf()
        for (document in result) {
            questionsList.add(document.data.pytanie);
        }
        textview.setText(questionsList.get(count));
        textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
            }
        });
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", exception)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippets:-

```
 db.collection("quizz").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (counter == task.getResult().getDocuments().size()){
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                           String text =  task.getResult().getDocuments().get(counter).getData().toString();
                            textView.setText(text);
                            counter++;
                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```